# Freebase MQL Query - Getting Frequency for Award

Tags: freebase, mql

I'm new to Freebase mql querying and would like to get the /time/recurring_event/current_frequency for all awards (/award/award).

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

That query looks like this in MQL:

```
[{
  "type": "/award/award",
  "name": null,
  "/time/recurring_event/current_frequency": [{
    "id": null,
    "name": null
  }]
}]
```

In order to get *all* the results, you'll need to use a [cursor](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/mql-overview#querying-with-cursor-paging-results) to page through the results set.